# configuration issue with respect to .htaccess file on ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, apache2, php, web-development, .htaccess

I am building an application tshirtshop I have following configuration in

/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/tshirtshop

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/tshirtshop
        <Directory /var/www/tshirtshop>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

and following in .htaccess file in location

/var/www/tshirtshop/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# Enable mod_rewrite
RewriteEngine On
# Specify the folder in which the application resides.
# Use / if the application is in the root.
RewriteBase /tshirtshop
#RewriteBase /
# Rewrite to correct domain to avoid canonicalization problems
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
# Rewrite URLs ending in /index.php or /index.html to /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ .*/index\.(php|html?)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.(php|html?)$ $1 [R=301,L]
# Rewrite category pages
RewriteRule ^.*-d([0-9]+)/.*-c([0-9]+)/page-([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?DepartmentId=$1&CategoryId=$2&Page=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^.*-d([0-9]+)/.*-c([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?DepartmentId=$1&CategoryId=$2 [L]
# Rewrite department pages
RewriteRule ^.*-d([0-9]+)/page-([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?DepartmentId=$1&Page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^.*-d([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?DepartmentId=$1 [L]
# Rewrite subpages of the home page
RewriteRule ^page-([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?Page=$1 [L]
# Rewrite product details pages
RewriteRule ^.*-p([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?ProductId=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

the site is working on localhost and is working as if there is no .htaccess rule specified 
i.e. if I were to view a page as

```
 http://localhost/tshirtshop/nature-d2
```

then I get a 404 Error but if I view the same page as

```
http://localhost/tshirtshop/index.php?DepartmentId=2
```

then I can view it.

```
sudo apache2ctl -M
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 log_config_module (static)
 logio_module (static)
 mpm_prefork_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 alias_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authz_default_module (shared)
 authz_groupfile_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 cgi_module (shared)
 deflate_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 php5_module (shared)
 reqtimeout_module (shared)
 rewrite_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
Syntax OK
```

What is the mistake if any one can point out in above configuration, or else I need to check any thing else?

Comment: Will you accept your solution if that works?

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to solve problem,
what happens is when you install Ubuntu and use apache2 in it there is a default website which is activated as soon as apache2 is installed in ubuntu

so that default website which is active is

```
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default
```

what happens is I have 2 files in sites-enabled directory

```
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/tshirshop  
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default
```

when Ubuntu's Apache loads the vhosts from sites-enabled directory

it loads the vhost configurations in alphabetical order 
so 000-default was loaded before tshirtshop 
and in 000-default there is a line which is following

```
DocumentRoot /var/www
<Directory /var/www/>
            AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

Reasons my configuration was not working 
1) Note the `AllowOverride None`  in  000-default was getting priority over `AllowOverride all` in tshirtshop  (alphabetical loading of vhosts)  so this was the reason my .htaccess file was not loaded since the 000-default site configuration was loaded before reading tshirtshop vhost and it already carried a line `AllowOverride None`
2) In my /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/tshirshop file I wrote

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/tshirtshop
```

and was accessing the application as

```
http://localhost/tshirtshop
```

so I changed the vhost tshirtshop's DocumentRoot

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/tshirtshop
```

to

```
 DocumentRoot /var/www
```

and disabled the default site of Ubuntu's apache

```
sudo a2dissite default
```

Now my configuration of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/tshirtshop is being read and applied to.So now my .htaccess file is being respected.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether this is an Ubuntu related question and should be asked here.

But here is the problem I see. You are accessing the site via `http://localhost/tshirtshop`, while your `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/tshirtshop`  file's documentRoot and directory have `/var/www/tshirtshop`. This means that this file is not used as the config for localhost - according to those values site should be accessed from just `http://localhost` not `http://localhost/tshirtshop`.

This could happen if the file was not created in the `/etc/apache2/sites-available` folder and then enabled in the terminal (which would create a symbolic link to sites-enabled) after the default was disabled.

I don't know the enable and disable commands, since I use webmin to handle the setup of local test sites for me. And then edit my `/etc/hosts` file to be able to access on something else closer to the real url rather than localhost.

But back to the problem, using the wrong URL causes your rewriteRule to rewrite to `hhtp://localhost/index.php?DepartmentId=2` which would be correct if the site was accessed via just `http://localhost` and not `http://localhost/tshirtshop`. You can now see why you get a 404 error.